# why Clojure conatins? behave so strangely?

Tags: clojure

Why clojure output true fo first one and false for the second one

```
(def myset [3 5 7 11 13 17 19])
(defn check-n
[n]
(contains? myset n))

(check-n 1)
(check-n 20)
```

Comment: `myset` is a vector, not a set. If it were a set, you'd get the output you expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`contains?`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/contains_q) is function for checking keys in collection. It can be used with map:

```
(contains? {:a 1 :b 2} :a)
=> true
(contains? {:a 1 :b 2} :c)
=> false
```

or with vector- in this case, it checks whether vector contains given *index*:

```
(contains? [1 2 3] 0)
=> true
(contains? [1 2 3] 3)
=> false
```

If you want to check occurence of number, use `.contains` from Java:

```
(.contains [1 2 3] 3)
=> true
```

or [`some`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/some) with set used as predicate:

```
(some #{3} [1 2 3])
=> 3
(some #{4} [1 2 3])
=> nil
```